# Numpy Mean Structured Array

Tags: python, numpy, mean, recarray

Suppose that I have a structured array of students (strings) and test scores (ints), where each entry is the score that a specific student received on a specific test.  Each student has multiple entries in this array, naturally.

### Example

```
import numpy
grades = numpy.array([('Mary', 96), ('John', 94), ('Mary', 88), ('Edgar', 89), ('John', 84)],
                     dtype=[('student', 'a50'), ('score', 'i')])

print grades
#[('Mary', 96) ('John', 94) ('Mary', 88) ('Edgar', 89) ('John', 84)]
```

How do I easily compute the average score of each student?  In other words, how do I take the mean of the array in the 'score' dimension?  I'd like to do

```
grades.mean('score')
```

and have Numpy return

```
[('Mary', 92), ('John', 89), ('Edgar', 89)]
```

but Numpy complains

```
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Is there a Numpy-esque way to do this easily?  I think it might involve taking a view of the structured array with a different dtype.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

#### Edit

```
>>> grades = numpy.zeros(5, dtype=[('student', 'a50'), ('score', 'i'), ('testid', 'i'])
>>> grades[0] = ('Mary', 96, 1)
>>> grades[1] = ('John', 94, 1)
>>> grades[2] = ('Mary', 88, 2)
>>> grades[3] = ('Edgar', 89, 1)
>>> grades[4] = ('John', 84, 2)
>>> np.mean(grades, 'testid')
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NumPy isn't designed to be able to group rows together and apply aggregate functions to those groups.  You could:

- use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and reconstruct the array;
- use [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), which is based on NumPy and is great at grouping; or
- add another dimension to the array for the test id (so this case would be a 2x3 array, because it looks like there were two tests).

Here's the `itertools` solution, but as you can see it's quite complicated and inefficient.  I'd recommend one of the other two methods.

```
np.array([(k, np.array(list(g), dtype=grades.dtype).view(np.recarray)['score'].mean())
          for k, g in groupby(np.sort(grades, order='student').view(np.recarray),
                              itemgetter('student'))], dtype=grades.dtype)
```

Comment: I don't understand how adding another dimension would help.

Comment: @Jeremy the extra dimension is for the test id.  So for 3 students and 2 tests you have a 2x3 array.

Comment: Right.  As it happens, in my program I do have a testid dimension already.  How does that help me?

Comment: @Jeremy then you can call `np.mean(axis=1)` over the test-id axis.

Comment: @Jeremy that would be ` numpy.zeros((3, 2), dtype=[('student', 'a50'), ('score', 'i')])` and then `grades[0, 0] = ('Mary', 96)`  etc.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15482/discussion-between-jeremy-and-ecatmur)

Answer (score 1):

matplotlib.mlab.rec_groupby was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit faster and simpler solution based on `itertools`, without using view(), is

`[(k,e['score'][list(g)].mean()) for k, g in groupby(argsort(e),e['student'].__getitem__ )]`

This is the same idea of ecatmur, but works in terms of indices employing argsort() instead of sort.

Answer (score 0):

collapseByField(grades,'student') gives what you want, after:

```
def collapseByField(e,collapsefield,keepFields=None,agg=None):
   import numpy as np
   assert isinstance(e,np.ndarray) # Structured array
   if agg is None:
       agg=np.mean
   if keepFields is None:
       newf=[(n,agg,n) for n in e.dtype.names if n not in (collapsefield)]
   import matplotlib as mpl
   return(mpl.mlab.rec_groupby(e,[collapsefield],newf))
```